# execute command when droppable target is filled with item

Tags: jquery, arrays, droppable

I'm trying to: http://jsfiddle.net/2phuW/12/

```
if ( //if target is filled with items) {
 //dosomething
}
```

But I can't get the logic to work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:- For now i am running an alert if it gets filled up.

I am just checking for the condition here to see if all slots are filled in.

```
$('.ui-droppable').find('span.closer').length == $('.ui-droppable').length


  if ($('.ui-droppable').find('span.closer').length == $('.ui-droppable').length) {
     alert('Listo ahora puedes simularlo');
     //if target is filled
     $(".status1").replaceWith('<i class="icon-check"></i> Listo ahora puedes simularlo'); //update status
      //put composition into params
   } else {
        $(".status1").replaceWith('<i class="icon-edit"></i> Sigue');
   }
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LdeGC/)